# Firebase: How to run a callback after all the initial "child_added" calls?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When listening on the "child_added" event with:

```
ref.on("child_added", function (snapshot) {

});
```

This callback function will initially run once for every child that exists in the reference.

> This event will be triggered once for each initial child at this location, and it will be triggered again every time a new child is added.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference

I want to take advantage of this fact along with the ordering functions in order to construct an ordered array:

```
orderedArray = [];

ref.orderByValue("rating").on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
    orderedArray.push(snapshot.val())
});

// how do I run a callback after the last child has been added?
```

However, there is no way (to my knowledge) to tell the last time the `child_added` callback has been called, thus I can't accurately run my own callback after the the last child has been added to my array.

---

Here's my workaround to this right now:

```
orderedArray = [];

ref.orderByValue("rating").on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
    orderedArray.push(snapshot.val())
});

setTimeout(function() {

    ref.off("child_added") // unbind event
    callback()

}, 3000)
```

This is pretty sketchy, especially in the case that it'll take more than 3 seconds to get all the data from the database.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can iterate over parent snapshot and order the children into an array using `DataSnapshot.forEach`:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref().child('items');
const items = [];
ref.once('value', snap => {
  snap.forEach(item => { items.push(item) });
  console.log(items);
});
```

Since you're calling `ref.off()` to read the data once, it makes sense that to use the `.once()` method and iterate of the parent snapshot instead.

Comment: and `forEach()` will read them in order even if I used an ordering function like `orderByValue()`?

Comment: What about cases when there is a large number of items in snap?  It sounds like this solution first loads all items in memory then gives them to the callback.

Comment: And how do you make it so that when a new state is added it is saved in the array? that's the intention I see when using `child_added` or this method is only for the report?

Answer (score 0):

What I try to do is use a `observeSingleEvent` listener.

```
// Following a Swift code but the logic remains same.
Database.database()
.reference(withPath: "The_Path")
.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    // Iterate and save the values from the snapshot.
    // Now initiate `childAdded` and `childChanged` listeners.
    self.keepObserving()
}
```

And on completion add `childAdded` and `childChanged`.

```
func keepObserving() {
    Database.database()
    .reference(withPath: "The_Path")
    .observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        // Check if the value in the snapshot exists in the your array or data model.
        // If not then add it to your container else return.
    }

    Database.database()
    .reference(withPath: "The_Path")
    .observe(.childChanged) { (snapshot) in
        // Find the indexOf the data in snapshot in array or container.
        // If the index is found or exist replace the changed value.
    }
}
```